# ContractException when serialize my custom datatable

Tags: wcf, serialization, datatable

I got error when try execute this wcf code

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>    contract: http://tempuri.org/:IService1 ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Method 'MyClassLibrary.MyDataTable.GetSchema()' must return a schema with a valid Id.
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.SchemaExporter.InvokeGetSchemaMethod(Type clrType, XmlSchemaSet schemas, XmlQualifiedName stableName)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.SchemaExporter.ExportXmlDataContract(XmlDataContract dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.SchemaExporter.ExportDataContract(DataContract dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.SchemaExporter.Export()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
>   ....
>   ...
>   ....

Custom datatable

```
Public Class MyDataTable
    Inherits DataTable

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

 End Class
```

My WCF Interface

```
 <ServiceContract()> _
 Public Interface IService1
   <OperationContract()> _
   Function TestDatatable(ByVal MyDT As MyDataTable) As Boolean
End Interface
```

Implementation

```
Public Class Service1
  Implements IService1

    Public Function TestDatatable(ByVal MyDT As MyClassLibrary.MyDataTable) As Boolean Implements IService1.TestDatatable

          Return MyDT.TableName = "MyTable"

     End Function
End Class
```

Note: When just using datatable its ok but not my custom datatable.

What need to be added do I can serialize my custom datatable.
I able to serialize my other object but not this class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually deriving from `DataTable` I'd create a typed data set using Visual Studio's data set designer. They are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of GetSchema method in DataTable looks like

```
protected virtual XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
      if (this.GetType() == typeof (DataTable))
        return (XmlSchema) null;
```

So that you may override this method in the following way

```
protected override XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return null;
}
```

This will resolve serialization issue.